# Microsoft Dynamics 4.0 Custom ASPX Page Identity

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

What is the recommended approach for obtaining the identity of the currently logged in MS Dynamics user from code behind for a custom ASPX page that lives in the ISV directory?

The approach for doing this must be agnostic of whether Dynamics is using AD/NTLM authentication or other authentication mechanisms and must not require enabling impersonation or changing the web.config.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `systemuserid` from the CRM database by executing a [WhoAmIRequest](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb890151.aspx) through the CRM web service and then get the `systemuser` record via `crmservice.Retrieve()`. As long as the user has any CRM security roles assigned at all, `WhoAmIRequest` and read access to their own `systemuser` record should always work.

Answer (score 0):

using the Xrm Context with the SDK

```
 public Xrm.systemuser CurrentUser   {
     get
     {
        var context = new XrmDataContext();

        var reponse = context.UsingService(
               service => (WhoAmIResponse)service.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest()));


        return (from user in context.systemusers
                where user.systemuserid == reponse.UserId
                select user).Single();
     }   }
```

or with the web services (called 'crm' here)

```
  public systemuser CurrentUser
  {
     get
     {
        WhoAmIRequest userRequest = new WhoAmIRequest();
        WhoAmIResponse current = (WhoAmIResponse)crm.Execute(userRequest);
        return (systemuser)crm.Retrieve(EntityName.systemuser.ToString(), current.UserId, new AllColumns());

     }
  }
```